# How to send facebook long live access token from server to browser?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I obtain long live access token with PHP SDK on server and want to send it back to browser to make api calls on behalf of user from browser instead of server. I have googled a lot but all I can find is lot of answered question on how to send token from browser to server or "you can send token from server to browser any way you want" which is not helping a lot.

Even fb developers page ends up  saying to simply send it back t client in any secure way.

However it doesnt seem to be that trivial to me because JS SDK will use access token that is stored in cookie named fbsr_appId. Does that mean that I have to simply set a cookie

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$fbCookie = array(
        'name'   => 'fbsr_appId',
        'value'  => /*long live access token fetched from db*/,
        'expire' => /*expire time of fbs long live access token*/,
        'domain' => 'www.my-site-name.com',
        'path'   => '/'
);
set_cookie($fbCookie);
```

I am using CodeIgniter but I would appreciate a lot any help explaining general idea of this action?

Comment: When you embed the JS SDK, you already have a valid short-lived token on the client. No need to send any token from the server in the first place.

Comment: Users can login using fb or tw. Both accounts are merged by email. Now imagine if users has merged the accounts, logs in with tw and is not logged in fb - he will be  logged in my website but JS SDK will not have access token so if he will share something from JS he will be promted to enter fb credentials. Thats why I am storing the long live access token and want to send it to browser if users logs into my website with tw and has previously merged fb account. I just consider that when user merges account he expects that he will not be promted to enter fb credentials anymore.

Comment: Facebook recommends a specific flow for this situation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code // And btw., your account matching by e-mail will fail in a lot of cases - not every user _has_ an e-mail on file with Facebook, f.e. if they registered using their mobile.

Comment: The link that you supplied is exactly from where I got the whole idea. I re-read it and finally understand that I am asking the wrong question, so thank you for that. The real question is what does fb mean with "Once you've retrieved the code from Facebook's server you then need to ship it to the client via a secure channel"? What would be the secure channel? P.S. Thank for your comment on account merging - will have to create option for user to choose the way they merge accounts.

Comment: I think secure channel means just HTTPS. They just don’t want you to send it over an HTTP connection, where it could easily be sniffed.